# HTML5 & Javascript Canvas game - How to make it possible for the player to save their game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, save

I am completely new to programming. I want to create a game using Javascript and the HTML5 canvases. The game will be a stealth zombie game and I need to create a permanent storage of scores. I also need to make it possible for them to save at a checkpoint and load it back up at a later date - after the game/webpage has been refreshed. How do I do that/what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Were are you keeping the scores, on your server or on the uses computer.  If it's the users computer you could use localStorage, if it's your server you will want to implement a POST request for your scores to be stored.

Comment: At the moment I have done nothing. I have barely started the game, I was just trying to think ahead. Which method would you suggest?

Comment: Storing your save on the Server or the Client, is a decision you need to decide first.  IOW: if you store on Client, only this browser / user has access to the high scores, eg. personal high scores.  Storing on the server allows you to have high scores for everybody who goes to your website.

Comment: Ok. So for high scores storing on the Server would be best. But for checkpoints, storing on the client would be better, since it would have to be suited for only that person. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, you could later have the ability to synchronise the score with the server if you so wanted.  So your best bet would be to start with `localStorage` first, as that's the easiest to do too.

Comment: Thank you. Does LocalStorage have any serious security issues to it?

Comment: Depends in what respect..   If your using `localStorage` for storing high scores, it's maybe not something you need to worry about.  But do bare in mind, anyone with html / javascript knowledge will be able to open up the inspector and look into your localstorage.  But if for example you was using localStorage to store usernames & passwords, then that's not  a good idea. :)

Comment: Ok. You've been so helpful. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a database for that. If you don't have  sql experience, I prefer you go with a nosql database such as [Mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/).